# How to create a drop down menu using taxonomy in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

I'm working on a shopping cart website where I've to add the 'Product' as a menu. The menu should be opened on mouse hover event and should display all product categories. I've added products with taxonomy like this -

-Product

--Cat-1

---Subcat-1

---Subcat-2

--Cat-2

---Subcat-1

---Subcat-2

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a menu that you're managing yourself, you can try [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus)